# Can I call Spring MVC actions from android and get json data?

Tags: android, ajax, rest, spring-mvc

I am writing a web-site using Spring MVC framework, and some of actions return json data to ajax calls from client's browser.(like dropdowns, search stuff, etc.)

Now, I also want to write an app for it.
So how can I get data for android? 
Can I just call those same actions that return json?
If not, then should I use REST or smth else?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I just call those same actions that return json?

Yes, you definitely can. These "actions" actually called **web-services** that return data in JSON format. Using androids Volley library you can make HTTP request and parse HTTP content that you get (whether it is JSON or html file)

Hope it helps :)